# Adding filter to an specific page/site direction

Tags: filters

I'm adding a filter to my WP site which replaces some names with the link to the specific site of those names.

For example:

```
function replace_text_wps($text){

 $replace = array(
 'XXX' => '<a href="https://example.org/XXX"><strong>XXX</a></strong>',
 'YYY' => '<a href="https://example.org/YYY"><strong>YYY</strong></a>'
 );
 $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
 return $text;
}
```

And adding the filter like this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps');
```

So, I was checking my site and all this stuff was correct, but I've just realized that I don't want the filter to work on blog posts (news, etc.)

So I tried this:

```
if ( ! is_single() ) {
    add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps');
}
```

But it doesn't work. I assume this is doable, so where is the mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Comment: try the if statement inside the replace text wps function

Comment: It worked! Thanks, didn't even think about that lol